# Latex rendering unicode plus minus (±) symbol incorrectly

Tags: unicode

From what I understand modern latex programs should be able to render unicode characters without any issue. However, the following MWE renders the `±` (ord 177 PLUS-MINUS SIGN) character as the `ś` chracter (ord 347: LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH ACUTE).

```latex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{parskip}%
%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
%
\begin{document}%
\pagestyle{empty}%
\normalsize%
13.787±0.020%
\end{document}
```

Running the command:

```
lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode document.tex
```

The PDF renders as:

[image]

I've also tried:

```
latexmk --pdf --interaction=nonstopmode document.tex
```

and

```
xelatex --interaction=nonstopmode document.tex
```

And I'ved tried changing `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.
The result is the same. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

For my use-case I'm auto generating a document with `pylatex`, so it's not as simple as replace the unicode character with `\textpm{}`. I really do want to be able to render unicode character as-is.

Comment: I get his from your example https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaATU.png. Is your tex system up-to-date? (side remark: with a current latex neither inputenc not textcomp are needed)

Comment: Oh,  you are using lualatex. Then don't use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, that is the wrong encoding for lualatex.

Comment: It's relatively recent: Running lualatex --version I get: `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)`. Do you have a newer version?

The textcomp and inputenc are coming from pylatex, but that's good to know. I did try manually without them and I got the same result. Marjin's answer works for me though.

Comment: I am away from computer but just tried your example on overleaf and got a plusminus symbol

Comment: @DavidCarlisle lualatex not pdflatex ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer removing fontenc did work.

Comment: you can also remove lmodern

Comment: the document should clearly not be used with luatex using T1 encoded 8bit fonts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With lualatex you shouldn't set the encoding to T1, also don't load inputenc and textcomp. If you remove  everything it will work:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{parskip}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\begin{document}%
\pagestyle{empty}%

13.787±0.020%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if fontenc would show a warning about this though.

Comment: All of your near-real-time responses has been amazing ! Thank you ♥

Comment: For anyone else using pylatex, removing these packages can be accomplished via kwargs of `Document`: e.g. `pylatex.Document(fontenc=None, lmodern=False, textcomp=False)`

Comment: @Erotemic pylatex should probably not add them by default if it's using luatex